# count rows in excel with multiple matched criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following data in a excel sheet and would like to count the number of rows that match specific criteria.

```
   A      B        C
1  Name   Status   Version
2  Joe    Open     1.0
3  Bob    Open     1.0
4  Joe    Closed   1.0
5         Open     1.0
6  Joe    Open     2.0
```

I would like to count all rows where;

1. Name is not empty, AND
2. Status is not "Closed", AND
3. Version is not "2.0"

based on the sample data above the count would be 2 (row 2 and 3 on the sheet)

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility: advanced use of the SUMPRODUCT() function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5<>""),--(B1:B5<>"Closed"),--(C1:C5<>"2.0"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I evaluated the formula in excel 2013 and it worked perfectly. I had been trying to get this outcome using `SUMPRODUCT` also, but had no luck. Can you explain why `--` is used in this case?

Comment: Hi Jamie, you're welcome. Rather than dig into the details of the 'SUMPRODUCT' function I would like to send you a couple of links to websites which explains all their secrets, e.g.: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/ and http://exceluser.com/formulas/sumproduct_12.htm. Anyway, basically the `--` part of `--(A1:A5<>"")` "transforms" the A1:A5 range/matrix/list (call it as you like) in a list of zeroes and ones based on the test (in this case the test says: "not equal to empty cell").

Answer (score 2):

Use this Array Formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A6<>"";1)*IF(B2:B6<>"Closed";1)*IF(C2:C6<>"2.0";1))
```

And hit **CTRL+SHIFT and ENTER**

The formula will evaluate to 2 rows as you suggested.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I evaluated the formula in Excel 2013 and it worked great, I did however have to change ";" to ",", i.e. `=SUM(IF(A2:A6<>"",1)*IF(B2:B6<>"Closed",1)*IF(C2:C6<>"2.0",1))` would have been great if you could explain why this needs to be an array formula in this instance tho

Comment: Yes seems like your locale are different (, instead of ;). This needs to be an Array Formula as we want the IF statements to return an array of results, otherwise the IF will return an error as it cannot process a whole range of values. If you select all the IFs and press key F9 the result will be {1;1;0;0;0} which is then summed up. Please select as answer to close the thread. Read more here :https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNTIFS()` for this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5, "<>",B1:B5, "<>Closed",C1:C5, "<>2")
```

That first comparison with `A1:A5` being `"<>"` is a little tricky, but it's just saying "If A1:A5 IS NOT NULL"

Comment: Using your formula evaluates to "3" in excel 2013 - I was expecting "2".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2013, COUNTIFS() is what you're looking for.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6,"<>"&"",B2:B6,"<>"&"closed",C2:C6,"<>2")
```

[Here's Microsoft's documentation on COUNTIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN).

[Here's a link for how to use criteria in COUNTIF() and COUNTIFS()](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/02/excel-countif-examples/).

Comment: Using your formula evaluates to "3" in excel 2013 - I was expecting "2".

Comment: My bad, those ranges should be 2:6, not 1:5.  It was counting the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table and set the filters with what You want. Put anything in the value as count. Many ways to handle this in a pivot.

Comment: I wanted to use the calculated value in a graph, would this have been possible using a pivot table?